# Can we push back struct containing vector without using constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets say I have a struct:

```
struct group{
    vector<int> a;
    vector<int> b;
    vector<int> c;
};
```

Then I create a vector of this struct:

```
std::vector<group> group_vec;
```

What I wanted was to do equivalent of

```
group obj;
obj.a.push_back(1);
obj.a.push_back(4);
obj.b.push_back(6);
obj.b.push_back(7);
group_vec.push_back(obj);
```

as

```
group_vec.push_back({{1,4},{6,7},{}}); // equivalent of above's object pushing
```

Comment: You wanted to do it, and did it not work when you went and did it?

Comment: @AndyG I had tried without -std=c++11 so it was giving me compilation error

Comment: After I tried with `-std=c++11` compilation flag it worked

Comment: Each element that you push into group_vec will try to fill in order the object elements (the inner vectors)... a believe the compiler generates a constructor for you in that case, but not 100% sure.

Comment: @solti: :-) We've all been there. Are you not allowed to use C++11, or is it okay to close this question as typo? Edit: You should be aware that you are creating a new `group` each time you call it that way, though, which I'm not sure is what you want.

Comment: I am allowed to use C++11 so closing would be ok

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL Yes I guess constructor is needed when the type of vector is not of primitive types

Comment: The point in the answer below, that the statement you've given *does* invoke constructors, is important. It's not clear what you mean by "without using constructor".

Comment: @KyleStrand Sorry abt that : what I actually meant was not writing constructor by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can do

```
group_vec.push_back({{1,2},{2,3}});
```

We do use constructors in that statement, but I assume that you meant "without a user defined constructor".